# Сохранение iframe

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Подскажите код или киньте, пожалуйста, ссылку на статью о том как сделать, чтобы при клике на кнопку сохранялся HTML код страницы из iframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вставить скрипт в тело iframe, по другому не получится. Это противоречит безопасности доступа.

Comment: У меня есть скрипт что бы сохранять html прямо со страницы сайта, но я не знаю как сделать с iframe его.